# Solspace Calendar: Export a single event

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm trying to add an export function to my calendar that will export a single event.

When I use the example code, it exports my entire calendar.

I tried passing a single event using this code:

```
{% set events = craft.calendar.event(craft.request.getSegment(3), ({
    loadOccurrences: false 
})) %}

{{ craft.calendar.export(events) }}
```

and I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Calendar\Library\Export\AbstractExportCalendar::__construct() must be an instance of Calendar\Library\Events\EventList, instance of Calendar\Library\Events\Event given, called in /craft/plugins/calendar/variables/CalendarVariable.php on line 128 and defined

Is there a way to export only individual events?

Answer (score 1):

There's a definitely a syntax error in your first line.

```
({
    loadOccurrences: false
})
```

should be:

```
{
    loadOccurrences: false
}
```

Also, from their docs, the [`export`](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar.export/) method only shows one parameter being passed in and you've specified two.